# Saving an array of objects to a text file

Tags: java, arrays, object

I'm trying to save the array objects (Room) to a .txt file. I'm not so familiar with serialization but I have tried using it as best as I can to write the objects to a file. However, I get this error code every time:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: hotelobjects.Room
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1378)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
at hotelobjects.HotelObjects.storeData(HotelObjects.java:81)
at hotelobjects.HotelObjects.main(HotelObjects.java:50)
```

This is the main code:

```
public class HotelObjects {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String command;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    Room[] myHotel = new Room[10];
    for (int x = 0; x < myHotel.length; x++) {
    myHotel[x] = new Room();
    }

    String roomName;
    int roomNum = 0;

    while (roomNum < 11) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter command : ");
        command = input.next();
        command = command.toLowerCase();

        if (command.charAt(0) == 'v') {
            viewCustomers(myHotel);
        }

        if (command.charAt(0) == 'a') {
            addCustomers(myHotel);
        }

        if (command.charAt(0) == 'e') {
            emptyRooms(myHotel);
        }

        if (command.charAt(0) == 's') {
            storeData(myHotel);
        }
    }
}

private static void viewCustomers(Room hotelRef []) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
            System.out.println("room " + x + " occupied by " + hotelRef[x].getName());
        }
}

private static void addCustomers(Room myHotel[]) {
    String roomName;
    int roomNum;
    System.out.println("Enter room number (0-10) or 11 to stop:");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        roomNum = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter name for room " + roomNum + " :");
        roomName = input.next();
        myHotel[roomNum].setName(roomName);
}

private static void emptyRooms(Room[] myHotel) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++ )
        if (myHotel[x].getName().equals("e"))System.out.println("room " + x + " is empty");
}

private static void storeData(Room [] myHotel) {
     try{
     FileOutputStream fos= new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Ganz\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\HotelObjects\\HotelObject.txt");
     ObjectOutputStream oos= new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
     oos.writeObject(myHotel);
     oos.close();
     fos.close();
   }catch(IOException ioe){
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/NotSerializableException.html

Comment: Have you googled `NotSerializableException`? It's pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/JavaRMI_10/?page=3

Comment: Your class need to implement java.io.Serializable

Answer (score 0):

The answer is already in the exceptionmessage. I'm missing the code of hotelobjects.Room, but i'd bet it's not implementing Serializable. The solution is to simply make Room implement Serializable.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have not implemented the `Serializable` Interface
Your `Room` class should look like this:

```
public class Room implements Serializable{
    public Room(){
        //...
    }
}
```